# Sent post request using CURL to SSL certified domain

Tags: php, curl

I need to sent from one (windows) server to another (Linux) server `POST` request using `CURL`, receiver domain has SSl sertificate.

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://receiver_url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("a"=>"aaa"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/wamp64/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

`errno` shows 0, but request is not sented, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick (and dirty) fix is to edit the following line:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

It configures cURL to accept any server (peer) certificate.

You can find a cleaner fix and more info about your problem [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

Comment: I already tried that "dirty" variant also, but requetst not sented anyway